# Unmarshalling XML

Tags: xml, go

I have the following XML which I want to unmarshal:

```
<packaging>
    <depth measurementUnitCode="MMT">1200</depth>
    <height measurementUnitCode="MMT">1320</height>
</packaging>
```

I want it to unmarshal into the following structs:

```
type Packaging struct {
    Depth Depth   `xml:"depth"`
    Height Height `xml:"height"`
}

type Measurement struct {
    UnitOfMeasure `xml:"measurementUnitCode,attr"`
    Value float64 `xml:"???????"`
}
```

The `UnitOfMeasure` is fine, but I can't figure how to get the actual `Value` set. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing specification should be `xml:",chardata"`.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/xml"

var text = `<data>1.23</data>`

func main() {
    data := struct {
        Value float64 `xml:",chardata"`
    }{}
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(text), &data)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/VMeIdCNVQB)